# Mono crashes in Ubuntu thread

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu-16.04

My program (below) works on Fedora 22 or if I call the thread function directly from main(). But if I launch the mono calls in a thread on Ubuntu 16.04, it asserts like this. Am I doing something wrong?

Howard Rubin

Output:

```
$ rm monotest.dll ; make ; ./monotest 
Mono C# compiler version 4.8.0.0 
mcs monotest.cs /out:monotest.dll /target:library 
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 
g++ monotest.cpp -o monotest -g3 -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` 
* Assertion at mono-threads-posix.c:265, condition `info->handle' not met 

Aborted (core dumped) 
$
```

==================================

```
// monotest.cpp 
#include <thread>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>

void Thread() { 
    MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init("monotest.dll"); 
    mono_jit_cleanup(domain); 
} 

int main() { 
    //Thread(); 
    std::thread t(Thread); 
    t.join(); 
}
```

==================================

```
//////////////////////// 
// monotest.cs 
namespace MyNamespace  { 

    public class MyClass { 
        public MyClass() { } 

        public void MySum(int arg1, int arg2) { 
            System.Console.WriteLine("MySum(" + arg1 + "," + arg2 + ") => " + (arg1 + arg2)); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

==================================

```
################### 
# Makefile 
monotest : monotest.cpp monotest.dll Makefile 
        @g++ --version | head -1 
        g++ $< -o $@ -g3 -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` 

monotest.dll : monotest.cs 
        @mcs --version 
        mcs $< /out:$@ /target:library
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for using threads in mono is woefully inadequate, but with experimentation threads can be made to work.

One way is to use mono_thread_create().

Another is to open the domain outside the threads with mono_jit_init(), then in the created threads call mono_thead_attach() at the beginning and mono_thread_detach() at the end.